# How can you use structural search to find constructor calls for subclasses of a given type?

Tags: intellij-idea, structural-search

I have an abstract class called "com.foo.BaseFoo"

I want to find anyone that calls new() on anything that extends from BaseFoo

I've tried doing a search template of:

```
new $BaseFoo$()
```

and then edited the variables to have an expression constraint on the type of the object to be

```
com.foo.BaseFoo
```

and clicked on the "Apply constraint within type hierarchy" but this hasn't worked.

Comment: when you write call 'new()' does it mean to call the method new() on the BaseFoo class hierarchy or is it related to the BaseFoo constructor ?

Comment: Idealy I'd like to find things where say we had

Foo and Boo that extends com.foo.BaseFoo, and in the code I'd want the structural search to find "new Foo()" or "new Boo()"

Answer (score 5):

You were almost there. Use a template like the following:

```
new $BaseFoo$($argument$)
```

Where $BaseFoo$
Text/regexp: `com\.foo\.BaseFoo`
check *Apply constraint within type hierarchy*

and $argument$
minimum count: 0
maximum count: unlimited